# Import PDF in my xamarin shared code application

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin, android-drawable

I want to import pdf in my xamarin android project.
I want to have a pdf in my application folder at the installation of the application.

Bu when i try to add this pdf in android ressources and try to open it, i get a path error.

i save my pdf in draxable ressource and call path like : @drawable/pdfname or pdfname. the two solution don t work.

Best regards,

Comment: include it as an asset

Comment: or place in raw folder.

Comment: ok, i put it in the asset folder.
I want to send email with attachement.
I try this but the app said me the file is empty.
` var file = new Java.IO.File("Assets/CV_2017.pdf");
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);`
i set my ressource as "build as android asset"

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Answer (score 0):

> ok, i put it in the asset folder. I want to send email with attachement. I try this but the app said me the file is empty. `var file = new Java.IO.File("Assets/CV_2017.pdf"); var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);` i set my ressource as "build as android asset".

To get the url of the file in assets folder, you can code for example like this:

```
var file = new File(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///android_asset/CV_2017.pdf").ToString());
if (file.Exists())
{
    var uri = file.AbsolutePath;
}
```

If you want to access the stream of the file under assets, you can use [AssetManager](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Res.AssetManager/) and code for example like this：

```
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("CV_2017.pdf")))
{
    //TODO：
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
I just want his URL. so i try with your first solution. y code never go in this if. 
The file.exists return false.

Comment: @JeanOriano, are you sure your file is placed in the `Assets` folder?